# Jasper report library version for java jdk 9 or higher

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Which version of Jasper report library support jdk 9 or higher
in my previous inventory management project I used ( java 8 , ireport designer for designing report,  jasper report library 5.6 )
now I want to use jdk 9 or higher
as it optimized by Oracle, as well as my project run faster with jdk 9
when I switched from jdk 8 to 9
my report not work.

Comment: You can find this information [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jasperreports/news/). For example, jdk11 is supported since *JasperReports 6.8.0*

Comment: i got it thanks Alex K

Comment: can we use jdk 17 with jasper report  6.18 ?

Comment: You can always try :)

Comment: thanks for help :)